# Regex with forward and backslashes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using a regex to check strings against a white-list. This regex will try to match any piece of account data. The particular string its getting hung up on is a date `10/12/2015`. The white-list should consist of alphanumeric characters and these special characters `\`, `/`, `-`, `@`, space, `.`, `,` and `#`.

```
Dim pattern As = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\/-@.,# _]*$"
```

This particular regex will be used in `VB.NET`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The escape character should go _**before**_ the character you are to escape. Did you try: `\/`?

Comment: I doubt you have a problem with a backslash. To define a backslash in a .NET regex, you use `"\\"`, and you have it right (i.e. your regex matches ``\`` ). BUT your regex also matches `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?` due to the *range*, `/-@`. That said, try `"^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\/@.,# _-]*$"` (note the `-` is at the end of the character class) *if* you need to match a ``\`` or remove ``\\`` from the pattern to not allow ``\`` in your strings.

Comment: If [Wiktor Stribiżew is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106747/regex-with-forward-and-backslashes#comment77184905_45106834) then you wouldn't need to escape the forward slash. If so, then what is the problem? _**Can't**_ it match forward slashes but it _**can**_ match backslashes?

Comment: @Visual Vincent tried that and it didn't work.  Still saying not a match

Comment: Post exact rules for the regex. Provide valid and invalid input strings.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Your rules do not include *at least 1 alphanumeirc*, but your regex has one - `(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])`. Besides, [there is no issue with the `10/12/2015` string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.*%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%29%5bA-Za-z0-9%5c%5c%2f-%40.%2c%23+_%5d*%24&i=10%2f12%2f2015). Still, the `-` must be at the end of the character class, and [it is still OK](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.*%5bA-Za-z0-9%5d%29%5bA-Za-z0-9%5c%5c%2f%40.%2c%23+_-%5d*%24&i=10%2f12%2f2015). Do you mean you need to allow ASCII letters, `/`, `,`, `-`, `@`, `.`, `,`, `#` chars?Then why did you add the ``\\``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I need to allow ASCII letters chars.

Comment: But do you want to allow a backslash? Or a comma? Besides, there is no issue with the string you mention.

Comment: I want to allow both forward and backslashes

Comment: Ok, let's talk code since *any piece of account data* does not really help what you are doing. [Your regex matches a backslash](http://ideone.com/4fkO9l) - regardless of whether the `-` is inside or at the end of the  character class.

Comment: I can leave out the backslash, but I still would need the forward slash

Comment: How about: `"^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\\/\-@.,# _]*$"`? I added another backslash to escape _both_ the backslash and the forward slash: `\\\/`. I also added an escape to the `-` after the forward slash: `\\\/\-`.

Comment: @developer_117: You are evading answering my argument: your regex **works** as it matches both `/` and ``\``. Show a fiddle proving it does not.

Comment: Ok, it looks like that works, but now if there is a space its not matching

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It seems now a `""` is what causing it not to match

Comment: @developer_117: Please provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I advise to rewrite the question from scratch, the current one is not answerable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I got it working with your regex.  Thanks for your help.  Please answer the questions and I will accept it.

Comment: You mean the one [in the fiddle](http://ideone.com/jZxhUN)? If not, please let know what regex you came up to, and I will be able to adjust your question and explain why it works.

Comment: this one "^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\\/\-@.,# _]*$" that you came up with.

Comment: Yeah, but you do not need to use `\/`. It is the same as `/`. And to match a `-`, put it either to the end or start of the character class, or after a range, or a shorthand character class.

Comment: @developer_117 : `this one "^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\\/\-@.,# _]*$" that you came up with.` - \*ahem, ahem\* it was actually I that wrote it ;) -- (not that it really matters though, and as Wiktor pointed out it was a bit superfluous with escape characters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution should look like

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\/@.,# _-]*$"
Dim s As String = "10/12/2015"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern))
```

See the [VB.NET demo](http://ideone.com/jZxhUN).

You do not need to escape `/` at all in .NET regex patterns, and to match a `-`, put it either to the end or start of the character class, or after a range, or a shorthand character class.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])` - a positive lookahead that requires a presence of an ASCII alphanumeric char after any 0+ chars other than a newline (LF, `.*`)
- `[A-Za-z0-9\\/@.,# _-]*`  - 0 or more ASCII letters (`A-Za-z`), digits (`0-9`) or `\` (matched with `\\`), `/`, `@`, `.`, `,`, `#`, space, `_`, `-` chars
- `$`  -  end of string.

To make the lookahead a bit more efficient, use the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast), replace `.*` with a negated character class `[^A-Za-z0-9]*` that matches 0+ non-alphanumerics:

```
"^(?=[^A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9\\/@.,# _-]*$"
```